# How to rebuild all databases in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server

SQL Server 2005 on Windows Server 2003, but recently operating system has broken down and I have to re-install system.

Is there any way to rebuild all databases when I re-install SQL Server 2005?

btw, master database and system databases files is backup

Comment: Install SQL Server, restore backup for each of your production databases, one by one - done! There is no "magic" way to getting back everything - you'll need to restore from your backups - that's what you have them for!

Answer (score 0):

do you mean restore w/o using data base backup files? then no you have to have some DB backup or copy of those DBs.

Comment: No. There are so many  different version databases on the server, now I just want to return to their original state of the server is not broken down